# Enviar authorization basic en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirección, auth

Cómo puedo enviar un Authorization Basic en laravel?
he intentado hacerlo de esta forma en las rutas pero no me funciona:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
$username = "Admin";
$password = "123";
$header = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password);
$pathtoFile = '/SQLConnect/test.php';   
return redirect($pathtoFile)->header("Authorization",$header);
```

})->name('test');

y también de esta otra forma

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
$pathtoFile = '/SQLConnect/test.php';   
return redirect($pathtoFile, 302, [
    'Authorization' => 'Basic '.base64_encode('Admin:123')
]);
```

})->name('test');

Pero no me funciona de ninguna de las 2 formas